# How to properly enable syntax highlighting for Mathematica in Vim?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

How to properly enable syntax highlighting for Mathematica in Vim?  I want it automatically on when opening .m files with Vim too.

Comment: You should ask this on [so]. For starters, you can use [this vimscript](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1273), but it is pretty primitive. Note that you will never be able to get the full power of the FE's highlighting engine, as vim will have no way of knowing the different scopings, contexts, etc.

Comment: Well well, you can: I use http://www.viplugin.com/ inside Wolfram Workbench and it works just great! This way one can work fast with WWB ...

Comment: @RolfMertig Does it turn the WB editor into a modal editor? If so, then that would be amazing!

Comment: @R.M  I installed mma.vim by putting it in `~/.vim/syntax/mma.vim`.  Now when I open *.m files, it still display white characters on black background as before.

Comment: Do you have a `.vimrc` setup? Do you have `syntax on` (need for highlighting)? Do you have `filetype on` (need for detecting mma files)? If not, then vim won't do anything. Also, I think it might only work with `.nb` files and not `.m` files (unless you explicitly set it)

Comment: I put `au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.m      set ft=mma sw=2` in `filetype.vim` and get error: `E477: No ! allowed: u! BufRead,BufNewFile *.m      set ft=mma sw=2`

Comment: These are problems for [so]. I would suggest deleting this and re-asking your specific problem there (search to see if it has already been asked)

Comment: btw, use `au` instead of `au!`... the latter removes all autocommands

Comment: @R.M: sure, it turns WWB into a modal editor. It's cool. And I don't care about special syntax coloring since the syntax coloring from WWB is just fine. Notice that this viplugin is just a vi - emulation, but it does work fairly well. I use it all the time.

Comment: @RolfMertig That's good to hear! I might actually give it a try sometime

Comment: @R.M I used to program in pure vi for a lot of years. And when WWB came along I understood it is a good idea, but did not like the editor. After finding viplugin I was just much more productive. A good editor matters a lot, and vi is one good and fast editor. It is a pity that WWB is not an integral part of the full Mathematica. I wonder how much of a percentage of Mathematica (novices) use WWB.

Comment: There is also eclim which can hook up eclipse to vim in several different ways. [eclim.org](http://eclim.org) is down atm, but the [githup repository](https://github.com/ervandew/eclim) is still there and seems to be active. (And this one is freeware btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a custom syntax file in two steps:

#### Create `~/.vim/syntax/mma.vim`:

```
# create directory(if not exist)
mkdir ~/.vim/syntax
cd ~/.vim/syntax

# download syntax file
wget https://github.com/vim-scripts/Mathematica-Syntax-File/raw/master/syntax/mma.vim
```

#### Create `~/.vim/filetype.vim`:

```
" my filetype file
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.m,*.nb       setfiletype mma
augroup END
```

---

Note: In Windows, change `~/.vim` to `C:\program files\vim\vimfiles`

Answer (score 4):

Place [this](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Mathematica-Syntax-File) in your `~/.vim/syntax` folder, then put

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.m setl ft=mma
```

in your ~/.vimrc.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax file for this, which you'll need to install.

http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1273

**install details**

> Install instructions are also in the file.
>
> Basically:
>
> - Drop mma.vim into $HOME/.vim/syntax/ 
>      (%HOME%\vimfiles\syntax\ for Windows)
> - Open a Mathematica file**

Comment: "as of May 2005,  this is included in Vim7" it says, and it seems to be built in to MacVim's package